# How to transform columns of data to a single column, where each row of data is stacked vertically in that column (in Postgres)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot

We have a horizontal data presentation like this:

```
|id|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
|01|1111|2222|3333|4444|5555|
|02|1234|5678|9012|3456|7890|
...
```

I would like to transform it to this:

```
|id|col|col_data|
|01|  1|    1111|
|01|  2|    2222|
|01|  3|    3333|
|01|  4|    4444|
|01|  5|    5555|
|02|  1|    1234|
|02|  2|    5678|
|02|  3|    9012|
|02|  4|    3456|
|02|  5|    7890|
....
```

I was able to list the `|id|col|` columns of my target table correctly using this:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    unnest((
        select
            array_agg(split_part(column_name::text, 'l', 2)::numeric)
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
        WHERE 
            TABLE_NAME = 'my_table' and 
            TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_schema'
    )) AS "col"
FROM my_schema.my_table
group by "col" id
ORDER BY id, "col";
```

But I don't know how to get the data from the source table in the desired format.

FYI:

- I don't have superuser privileges.
- The actual table has 26 columns

Answer (score 1):

One way is a lateral join if all columns have the same data type:

```
select t.id, up.*
from the_table t
  cross join lateral (
    values (1, col1), (2, col2), (3, col3), (4, col4), (5, col5)
  ) as up(col, col_data);
```

---

If you don't care that everything is converted to text (not preserving the original data types), you can use JSON to unpivot the columns:

```
select t.id, 
       up.col, 
       up.col_data
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(t) - 'id') as up(col, col_data)
```